# how to use recursion for converting String to int

Tags: java, string, recursion, int

I want to convert String input into int using recursion. This is the code I came up with but if my input is 123456 it only returns 124. If I enter 1234567, it gives an error.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Problem1 {
static int x =0;
static int counter = 0;
//input
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
 String s= scan.nextLine();
 System.out.println(recursive(s));

}
 //recursive method
public static int recursive(String s){
    if(s.length()==1){
        x=(x*10)+ Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,1));
        return x;
    }
    else{
        x = (x*10)+Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,1));
        counter++;
        return recursive(s.substring(counter,s.length()-1));


    }

    }
}
```

Comment: What does your o/p expect ? Why r u multiplying it by 10 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problem1 {
    static int x = 0;
    static int counter = 0;

    // input
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(recursive(s));

    }

    // recursive method
    public static int recursive(String s) {
        if (s.length() == 1) {
            x = (x * 10) + Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 1));
            return x;
        } else {
            x = (x * 10) + Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 1));
            counter++;
            return recursive(s.substring(1, s.length()));

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your static `counter` variable. You are incrementing it every time. But you only want to have the substring starting at 1 (so cut off the first "letter").

So instead of using:

```
counter++;
return recursive(s.substring(counter,s.length()-1));
```

consider using:

```
return recursive(s.substring(1));  // you even don't really need the length
```

Because the `String s` parameter is as follows:

```
1st call: 1234567
2nd call: 234567
3rd call: 34567
4th call: 4567
...
```

So, you only have to cut off the first letter.

Btw: your sample "project" is a really funny one ;)

Answer (score 0):

A few notes to start:

1. If you're doing recursion, you probably don't want to use a member variable. It's not wrong to do so, but not really typical of the pattern (your x variable).
2. It's often handy to pass in state through the recursion, although you wouldn't have to (that is, current value of x).
3. Your case is a little odd because you have to change your current parse value for every sub-parse (shifting by 10 each time); makes it a little more complicated.
4. If you are going to keep x as a member variable (which does seem to make sense in this case), you don't need to return anything from recursive.
5. Can you really not just use Integer.parseInt()?

Code could be much more simple, something like:

```
 void recursive (String s)
 {
   if (s.length() == 0) return 0;
   x = x * 10 + Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 1));
   recursive(s.substring(1));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
recursion("1234567", 0, 1)
```

The above code will turn the string "1234567" into an int using recursion. You must pass the string you want to convert, and then 0 and 1.

```
public static int recursion(String s, int result, int place) {
    result += place * Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(s.length() - 1) + "");
    if(s.length() == 1) {
        return result;
    }
    else {
        return recursion(s.substring(0, s.length() - 1), result, place * 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int computeStr(String str) {
        if (str.equals("")) {
            return 0;
        }

        int x = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
            x = x * 10;
        }
        x = x * Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, 1));
        return x + computeStr(str.substring(1));
    }
```

For example: "2432" is (2 * 1000) + (4 * 100) + (3*10) + (2*1) = 2432
this algorithm begins at first position (2) from 2432

Answer (score 0):

I know its kind of a late response but you could try something like this :-

```
    private static int stringToInt(String string) {
    if (string.length() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int rv;
    int num = string.charAt(string.length() - 1) - '0';
    String restOfTheString = string.substring(0, string.length() - 1);
    rv = stringToInt(restOfTheString) * 10 + num;
    return rv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Subtracting the ASCII code of the '0' character from your character returns an integer:

```
public class StringRecursion {
    static int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(convertStringToInt("123456"));
    }

    public static int convertStringToInt(String input) {
        if (input.length() == 1)
            return input.charAt(0) - '0';

        int value = convertStringToInt(input.substring(0, input.length() - 1));
        counter++;
        return value * 10 + input.charAt(counter) - '0';

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this :

```
public static int conStrToInt(String str) {


    if(str.length()==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    char cc = str.charAt(0);
    String ros = str.substring(1);

    int factor=1;
    for(int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++)
        factor*=10;

    factor=factor*(cc-'0');
    return factor+conStrToInt(ros);

}
```